# Server Implementation of a web based silverlight card game

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have to develop an in-browser card game using silverlight. The game requires exactly four players to play. Now what i have read online, is that i have to implement that game logic on a a server and handle game event via sending webservice requests to that server.
My question is, how can we implement a server, which can handle multiple instances of game [loop]. I have no idea how will the server handle separate instance of the game for groups of 4 people. 
I want all the people to connect to the server and and then be able to run an instance of the game after selecting the other 3 players. A sucky paint diagram is attached for more clarification. So how can i achieve that ? [image]

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please, make it more specific to your actual problems.

Comment: If you accept that is is actually turn-based and not real-time you just treat is as a database problem. Use tables to track instances of `games`, `players`, `turns`, `hands`, `cards`, `scores` etc. Each Silverlight client then just does regular updates to keep each screen refreshed. Then you just have to track game-state (e.g. as various status fields in the `game` table). Your server logic just becomes a state engine.

Comment: @HiTech I thought about your idea, but will it be efficient to repeatedly probe the server [DB] for changes? What will be the threshold if one of the players gets disconnected unusually?

Comment: Do not get hung up on efficiency until you actually see something is too slow. You would normally cache recent/frequent data in memory on the server. Re disconnection: your state engine just needs to take lack of response into consideration. It's all just data after all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's a bunch of stuff to think over: persistence, concurrency, security, parallel game sessions possibility, player synchronization logic, etc.

But in general, your server should somehow keep track of all game sessions and assign unique identifiers to them. It also should assign identifiers to all active clients. Each client then uses its own identifier and a session identifier to request other player's moves or post its own. All moves must be timestamped so that clients may get updates.